# Swift - Como pego uma imagem da internet e mando para uma ImageView?

Tags: swift

Possuo uma ImageView, quero pegar uma imagem da internet (através de um link) e jogar pra ImageView na tela.

Exemplo de imagem a ser capturada:
   http://likefotos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/paisagem-tailandia1.jpg

Como quero que apareça

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc. está usando Mac ou a versao free no Linux ?Porque no Linux ainda nao tem as foundations liberadas. Ainda assim a versao free da usar com lib chamada Zewo que é só procurar no github.

para Mac vc. já viu aqui ?  ->

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift

Comment: Era em Mac. Funcionou aqui da forma mostrada neste link. Obrigado.